# ASP.NET Core Web API - How to Correct Object reference not set to an instance of an object in DBContext

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

In ASP.NET Core 6 project, I am implementing Entity Framework code-first.

I am trying to get the user name of the logged in user in the `ApplicationDbContext` for audit log purposes.

I have this code:

```
public interface ICurrentUserService
{
    public string UserId { get; }
    public string UserName { get; }
    bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
    public string IpAddress { get; }
}

public class CurrentUserService : ICurrentUserService
{
    public string UserId { get; }
    public string UserName { get; }
    public bool IsAuthenticated { get; }
    public string IpAddress { get; }

    public CurrentUserService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        IpAddress = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Connection?.RemoteIpAddress.ToString();
        UserName = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Name);
        UserId = httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.User?.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        IsAuthenticated = UserId != null;
    }
}

public interface IDateTime
{
    DateTime Now { get; }
}
```

Then in the `ApplicationDbContext`, I have:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>,ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>,IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    private readonly ICurrentUserService _currentUserService;
    private readonly IDateTime _dateTime;

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options,
        ICurrentUserService currentUserService, IDateTime dateTime)
        : base(options)
    {
        _currentUserService = currentUserService;
        _dateTime = dateTime;
    }

    public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        OnBeforeSaveChanges(_currentUserService?.UserName);

        foreach (var item in ChangeTracker.Entries<AuditableEntity>())
        {
            switch (item.State)
            {
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    item.Entity.LastModifiedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.LastModifiedAt = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Added:
                    //item.Entity.Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                    item.Entity.CreatedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.CreatedAt = _dateTime.Now;
                    break;

                case EntityState.Deleted:
                    item.Entity.DeletedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
                    item.Entity.DeletedAt = _dateTime.Now;
                    item.Entity.IsDeleted = true;
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        return await base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    private void OnBeforeSaveChanges(string userId="SYSTEM")
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        var auditEntries = new List<AuditEntry>();

        foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entry.Entity is AuditTrail || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                continue;

            var auditEntry = new AuditEntry(entry);
            auditEntry.TableName = entry.Entity.GetType().Name;
            auditEntry.UserId = userId;
            auditEntries.Add(auditEntry);

            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;

                if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                {
                    auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                    continue;
                }

                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Create;
                        auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Delete;
                        auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        if (property.IsModified)
                        {
                            auditEntry.ChangedColumns.Add(propertyName);
                            auditEntry.AuditType = AuditType.Update;
                            auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                            auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (var auditEntry in auditEntries)
        {
            AuditLogs.Add(auditEntry.ToAudit());
        }
    }
}
```

Login:

```
public async Task<Response<LoginResponseDto>> Login(LoginRequestDto model)
{
    var response = new Response<LoginResponseDto>();
    _logger.Information("Login Attempt");
    var user1 = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
    var userState = _dbContext.ApplicationUsers.Where(u => u.UserName == model.UserName).Select(m => m.IsActive).FirstOrDefault();
    if (userState == false)
    {
        //_logger.Error("Login operation failed");
        response.Message = "User account is not active. Kindly contact the Administrator";
        response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        response.Successful = false;
        return response;
    }
    var validityResult = await ValidateUser(model);
    if (!validityResult.Successful)
    {
        //_logger.Error("Login operation failed");
        response.Message = validityResult.Message;
        response.StatusCode = validityResult.StatusCode;
        response.Successful = false;
        return response;
    }

    //var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
    var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(model.UserName);
    var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
    var refreshToken = _tokenGenerator.GenerateRefreshToken();
    user.RefreshToken = refreshToken;
    user.RefreshTokenExpiryTime = DateTime.Now.AddDays(7); //sets refresh token for 7 days
    user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now;
    var result = new LoginResponseDto()
    {
        Id = user.Id,
        Token = await _tokenGenerator.GenerateToken(user),
        RefreshToken = refreshToken,
        User = _mapper.Map<UserDto>(user),
        Roles = roles,
        Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2)
    };
    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user);

    response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.OK;
    response.Message = "Login Successfully";
    response.Data = result;
    response.Successful = true;
    return response;
}
```

When user logs in, I get this error:

> System.NullReferenceException
> HResult=0x80004003
> Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This line of code is highlighted:

```
item.Entity.CreatedBy = _currentUserService?.UserName;
item.Entity.CreatedAt = _dateTime.Now;
```

in `public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync`.

They are both null. How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: why is `public override async Task<int> SaveChangesAsync` called when users login?

Comment: @IsaacIkusika - I didn't call it when user logs in, I only update the logged in time using user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now.   See my code.

Comment: oh, my bad. ‍♂️ The line of code you highlighted - that the exception is thrown from - is from when the `EntityState` is `Added`. Shouldn't it be from `Modified`? I suggest you add a breakpoint and check the value of `item` in the `foreach` block.

Comment: By *"They are both null"* do you mean `_currentUserService` and `_dateTime` fields? If yes, check if the correct constructor of your `ApplicationDbContext` is called and what it receives in arguments.

Comment: Have you checked that whetever be null of `httpContextAccessor` in `CurrentService` construction?

Comment: Was this ever solved? Getting something similar